# Why artifact has no classes?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, libraries, jcenter

This is my module (Library) build.gradle file and I uploaded my library then when I'm trying to test it using this line 
compile 'com.abanoub.androidlib:walkthrough:1.0.0:release@aar'
the artifact has no classes ..
Help please :)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'walkthrough'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.abanoub.androidlib'
    libraryName = 'Walkthrough'
    artifact = 'walkthrough'

    libraryDescription = 'A simple android library to make a simple walkthrough activity'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/AbanoubAsaad/Walkthrough'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/AbanoubAsaad/Walkthrough.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.2'

    developerId = 'abanoubasaad'
    developerName = 'Abanoub Samaan'
    developerEmail = 'abanoub_samaan@hotmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    publishNonDefault true

   defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Comment: Your dependency identifier seems odd (or unknown to me): `com.abanoub.androidlib:walkthrough:1.0.0:release@aar` normally it should more look like `com.abanoub.androidlib:walkthrough:1.0.0@aar`. Have you checked the jar that is uploaded to jcenter? Is it a valid jar with classes?

Comment: http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/abanoub/androidlib/walkthrough/1.0.0/
This is what uploaded to jcenter ..

Comment: As the aar file is with no classes, the creation of that aar seems to be broken. Are you sure that the generation knows where your classes are? Have you put the classes in the correct src folder?